# How do I Get screen resolution in php & insert in log file?

Tags: php, email, screen-resolution

Well, I have planning for Detecting Email Open but it has been done. By using PHP i want to detect customer screen resolution & want to insert in log through email? Please share code.

Comment: Try some, but not possible with php only.

Comment: Javascript would work for this

Comment: Try javascript but not put output in log file,
$width = " <script>document.write(screen.width); </script>";
$height = " <script>document.write(screen.height); </script>";

$tot1 =  $width; $tot2 = $height;
 echo $tot1;
 echo ' x';
 echo $tot2;

Comment: Please give me ans...